# SSE int64 Intrinsics

Tags: c++, sse

Please i'm tryin to do some optimization on some int64 arithmetic. I need to do oprations like right and left shift, division, remainder and all, buh i've search all SSE intrinsics and found nothing. The Left shift doesnt work well with negative values. Pls can u guide me??

A part of the code is shown(on intel i7):

```
u_a2b2=(MatrixAiB1[0]>>2*z_bits);
res_ri=(MatrixAiB1[0] % (__int64(1)<<2*z_bits));
if (MatrixAiB1[0] >= 0)                         
  {
     if (abs(res_ri) > (__int64(1)<<41))    
     {          
         u_a2b2=u_a2b2+1;
     }
   }
else
{
     if (abs(res_ri) < (__int64(1)<<41))    
     {
        if (u_a2b2>=0)
         {
        u_a2b2=u_a2b2-1;
         }
       else 
        {
        u_a2b2=u_a2b2+1;
        }
      }

}
```

Everything is int64

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question as written is a bit rambling.  It would help if you could post a complete but minimal program which tries to do one thing that you want and point out what exactly is wrong with it.

Comment: It is far from clear what you are trying to achieve, and what you are trying to improve. The code itself doesn't appear to work on arrays or anything like that, so for a 64-bit build of your code there would be absolutely no help from SSE instructions (most likely, it would make it slower). For a 32-bit build, SSE instructions MAY be a tiny bit faster for the shifts (divide or modulo is the same speed anyway, since the hard part is the actual divide, which happens in the same divide unit, whether it came in as an SSE or "regular" instruction).

Comment: There is no integer remainder (or even integer division) in SSE anyway.

Comment: Thanks all. Well in d actual code, the MatrixAiB1 is quiet big. Could have about 5184 elements and more. However, each result is made up of 3 results packed in one (thus the use of 1nt64). I'm just trying to unpack. I really see SSE nd AVX are more for floating point arithemetic

Comment: @Jane: How often are you doing that operation? Because 5184 elements is not really all that big unless you are doing it alot of times. Besides it might help, if you would tell us what that code tries to accomplish (it looks like it could be a bit overly complicated, possibly due to a vain atempt to make it faster)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Where do you see a divide or modulo operation in that code? I can only see an binary and-operation pretending to be a modulo.

Comment: @Grizzly: Second line of the code has `%` in it, which is modulo.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: A modulo by a power of two, which should be transformed into an and operation by any optimizing compiler (which is what I meant by pretending)...

Comment: Some compilers will do that, but typically, if you actually want it to be just a simple and operation, you have to make it an `&`, since (at least for regular divide) will perform extra operations to do with negative numbers - even if you don't ever hit negative numbers. Check the generated code.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, there's no point in trying to optimise this sort of code. Just declare a variable with a 64 bit size and let the compiler do the rest. On 64 bit builds, the instructions generated will all be CPU intrinsic (i.e. just a single CPU instruction) and on 32 bit builds the compiler writers will already have done the hard work of finding the best way to implement the 64 bit operations on a 32 bit system.

Comment: +1: just to re-iterate the most important point: compile with `g++ -m64` (or equivalent for your compiler) so that you generate 64 bit code.

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
 res_ri=(MatrixAiB1[0] % (__int64(1)<<2*z_bits));
```

could probably be replaced with:

```
 res_ri=(MatrixAiB1[0] & (__int64(1)<<2*z_bits)-1);
```

(if the result is supposed to be either negative or positive, you will need an something to fix that up, but it's "imlementation defined" if one of the sides of `%` is negative, so I guess you shouldn't be relying on what happens if `MatrixAiB1[0]` is less than zero).

The `&` operation is about 20 times faster than `%`, so should give a nice improvement of about 100000 clock cycles for 5000 elements.

Comment: Yes, that could be done. It most likely won't do anything to improve the runtime though, for the simple reason that compilers do know this trick (and can prove that the operand is a power of two in this case, which is not always possible). So there should be no reason to make the code less readable by doing something the compiler should be able to do anyways. And even if it didn't it might not give that much improvement depending on the predictability of the if-condition (of course assuming that the sequence isn't completely reordered with the jumps being replaced by conditional moves).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some SSE2 and a lot more AVX2 intrinsics for dealing with 64bit integers. If you processor supports AVX2 you can really speed up your code by dealing with 4 64bit values at a time...

You can find a pretty comprehensive listing here: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/.